# Adding pop-out images to a floorplan in Wordpress

Tags: image, javascript, media, thumbnails

this is a general web design question but seeing that the site I have built for my client was built using wordpress I will ask it here first.

My client has a lodge/chalet with 2 floors. She has supplied CAD drawn floor plans of both floors and photos of all the rooms. She has asked if I could add the functionality of showing image popup's of the rooms as the mouse pointer is hovered over each separate room in the original floor plan image. I understand that somehow I would need to create zones overlaying the original image, with mouse over css rules which display the photos.

I think it is a lovely idea and hope some clever soul could point me in the right direction of achieving this.

Many thanks

Comment: I have since found this plugin which is going to do this job just perfectly. https://wpdrawattention.com

Answer (score 1):

I would split up the floor plan into smaller sections (squares or rectangles), put them into divs as backgrounds, then add CSS or jQuery for mouse over on the divs to popup said images.

Comment: great idea, If i could get them all to load so that there are no gaps between each one then the original image will still look like one whole image. Thanks